# ScriptApp.getOAuthToken not getting the right permissions for drive through url fetch app?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Trying to explore this with a very simple script but I'm getting an insufficient permissions error:

```
  function mini(){
    var gdriveId = "1hp8ncIG4Ww7FH8wi7HjJzzzzzzz";
    var options = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
        },
   }
   var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/"+gdriveId+"/children";
   var response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch( url,  options).getContentText());
  }
```

I tried enabling the v2 drive api in the advanced google services dropdown but that didn't work.

Comment: Perhaps you need to add the scope to your manifest.

Comment: Do  you require an id at the end of your Url? Documentation Suggests this pattern:`GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/folderId/children/childId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your situation and goal as follows.

- From `gdriveId` in your script, I thought that you want to retrieve the folder list in the root folder of `gdriveId` using the method of "Children: list" in Drive API v2.
- You have already enabled Drive API at Advanced Google Services.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- When your script is put to new GAS project and Drive API is enabled at Advanced Google Services, the scopes of the project is only `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request`. The required scope can be automatically detected by the script editor. But, even when Drive API is only enabled, it seems that no scopes are added. I think that the reason of your issue is this.

  - Under above situation, if you want to retrieve the access token including the required scopes, in order to make the script editor automatically detect the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`, for example, please put `// DriveApp.getFiles()` to the script as a comment line.
  - In this case, when you use the methods for other scopes in your script, those scopes can be automatically detected and added by the script editor.

#### Modified script 1:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

```
function mini(){
  var gdriveId = "1hp8ncIG4Ww7FH8wi7HjJzzzzzzz";
  var options = {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
      },
 }
 var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/"+gdriveId+"/children";
 var response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch( url,  options).getContentText());
}

// DriveApp.getFiles()  // <--- Added this comment line. By this, the scope of https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly is added.
```

#### Modified script 2:

When the method of Advanced Google service is used, the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` is automatically added. By this, the following script works.

```
function test() {
  var gdriveId = "1hp8ncIG4Ww7FH8wi7HjJzzzzzzz";
  var res = Drive.Children.list(gdriveId);
  console.log(res)
}
```

#### Other pattern:

From June 1, 2020, the files and folders in the shared Drive can be retrieved by Drive service. So you can also use the following script.

```
function myFunction() {
  const getFolderList = (id, folders = []) => {
    const f = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);
    const fols = f.getFolders();
    let temp = [];
    while (fols.hasNext()) {
      const fol = fols.next();
      temp.push({name: fol.getName(), id: fol.getId(), parent: f.getName()});
    }
    if (temp.length > 0) {
      folders.push(temp);
      temp.forEach((e) => getFolderList(e.id, folders));
    }
    return folders.flat();
  };

  var gdriveId = "###"; // Please set the Drive ID.
  const res = getFolderList(gdriveId);
  console.log(res);
}
```

#### References:

- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Children: list of Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/children/list)
- [Authorization Scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes)

Comment: Thanks tanaike. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @J. G. Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give permission to write with ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(), just add the following code in a commented out form and authorize it at runtime. If you don't do this, you'll only be able to download and browse.

```
//DriveApp.addFile("test");
```

Reference URL：https://00m.in/UeeOB

Comment: Please don't use URL shorteners because they can easily lead to linkrot. Also, this answer is contained in @Tanaike's earlier answer.